# How to eliminate 'The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound' error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, it's supposed to return results of non validated accounts in a database, that were created after a certain date. I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to eliminate it. Here is the query:

```
select count(*) (nolock)
from dbo.[User]
where ID is not null
and UserStatusID!=2
and CreateDateTime>='5/1/2012'
and not exists (select userid from dbo.UserValidation where dbo.[User].UserID=dbo.UserValidation.UserID)
```

It errors out on the "where dbo.[User].UserID=dbo.UserValidation.UserID" What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just Change it to [User].UserId without the dbo same with dbo.UserValidation.UserID , you don't need the schema

Comment: Do you really have two fields in user, id and userid?

Comment: I erased the beginning part of "ID" for security reasons. :-)

Comment: The only thing that seems wrong with the syntax of the query is the placement of "(nolock)", which should go after the table name. But that wouldn't produce the error you're getting.

Comment: actually, once i moved the (nolock), the error went away..... not exactly sure why, i didn't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing the tables:

```
select count(*) (nolock)
from dbo.[User] u
where ID is not null
and UserStatusID != 2
and CreateDateTime >= '5/1/2012'
and not exists (select uv.userid from dbo.UserValidation uv where u.UserID = uv.UserID)
```

Without the schema:

```
select count(*) (nolock)
    from [User] u
    where ID is not null
    and UserStatusID != 2
    and CreateDateTime >= '5/1/2012'
    and not exists (select uv.userid from UserValidation uv where u.UserID = uv.UserID)
```

Comment: This method only moves that error over to the "u.UserID=uv.UserID)" part.

Comment: @Skrubb, try it without the schema qualifier.  It's possible that your UserValidation table was assigned to a different schema.

Answer (score 0):

While doing a `JOIN` it's always better to explicitly qualify all the columns in query like below.

```
select count(u.userid)
from [User] u
where u.ID is not null
and u.UserStatusID != 2
and u.CreateDateTime >= '5/1/2012'
and not exists 
(
select uv.userid 
from UserValidation uv
where uv.UserID = u.UserID
)
```

Comment: you don't want to join on a new table in the subquery because the op is trying to tie the outer `User` table to the inner `UserValidation` table.

Comment: @ps2goat, that's correct. Edited answer; was concentrating on syntax.

Comment: I updated it to also alias the UserValidation table in the inner query

Comment: @ps2goat, thanks for the edit but in inner query you don't need alias for the table present in `FROM` clause; though that can be done for more readability.

Comment: I did it just for clarity, since the column exists in both tables.